# GET request in google drive api with api key

Tags: oauth, google-api, google-drive-api, google-oauth

According to the google drive api's documentation, I can not write key parameter into the request.
I tried this request with my folderID and my api key:

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q='folderID'+in+parents&key={API KEY}
```

The documentation page contains a [try-out method](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list#try-it) where I tried out my request, I ticked only the API key in the credentials section. This also did not work.

Can I make requests with api key or not?

Comment: Please defile  **without any success** I am assuming you got an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

API keys are used for accessing public data.  Not private user data.

The [files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) requires that your application be authorized with one of the following scopes

[image]

trying to call files.list without authorizing the call using Oauth2 is going to result in the following error message

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "insufficientFilePermissions",
    "message": "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file."
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file."
 }
}
```

The only method in the google drive API that you would be able to use with an API key would probably be a file.get assuming that the file itself was set to public.  As in shared with everyone.

Api keys are mostly used for apis like maps, or youtube searching for public videos.