# 'The user does not have sufficient permissions for this file.' error when trying to list the files on my google drive using api key

Tags: reactjs, google-cloud-platform, next.js, google-drive-api

I am trying to list all the files on my Google Drive using the Google Drive API in my Next.js application. However, when I execute the code, I receive an error with a status code of 403 in the response.

```
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server';
import { google } from 'googleapis';

export async function GET() {
  try {
    const drive = google.drive({
      version: 'v3',
      auth: 'apikey here' 
    });

    const fileId = 'fileid here'; 

    const exportedDoc = await drive.files.list({
    });

    console.log('Exported Google Docs file:', exportedDoc);


  } catch (e) {
    console.error('Error exporting Google Docs file:', e);
    throw e;
  }

  return NextResponse.json({ message: '' });
}
```

I have already provided my API key where it says apikey here, and I've also replaced 'fileid here' with the actual ID of the file I want to access.

Despite these changes, I'm still encountering a 403 error in the response. I have double-checked my API key and file ID to ensure they are correct.

I would appreciate any insights or suggestions on how to resolve this issue and successfully list all the files on my Google Drive using the Google Drive API.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Are you sure you're using the proper authentication method? AFAIK google requires OAuth 2.0 creds instead of an API key for user files.
Do you need to enable google drive api in your cloud console?

Comment: You can use an API Key with a Google Drive Shared URL. Otherwise, you must use OAuth 2.0 and create an Access Token from a user or service account. To use a service account requires additional steps: https://support.google.com/drive/answer/7166529

Comment: Also, see this answer from one of the experts: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72733498/8016720